# how to make sync automatically directory on centos linux

Tags: linux, directory, synchronization

I created directory in:
**/home/a & /home/b**

I would like to sync between folder a & b. Assume when I create directory or file in **/home/a** of cource in **/home/b** will be created automatically, and also when I delete **/home/b/*** in **/home/a/*** will be deleted.

I did this: 
# cd /home 
# mkdir a && mkdir b 
# rsync -r a b && rsync -r b a

but not working. 
I will appreciate who can help. Big Thanks

Comment: What is not working? Do you get an error? If yes, what is the error?

Comment: no error, but it doesn't automatically sync. I also type rsync -r a b in terminal to get new file. any suggestion?

Comment: Try -v to show debug info